# Magento backend customer creation not syncing with api_user table

Tags: mysql, database, magento, e-commerce

Currently, if we create a customer in the admin panel / backend of our site, that customer is unable to login using the email address we used in creating the customer profile. Even after resetting the password using a custom and self -generated one.

I looked at the database and noticed that customers’ emails that sign-in through the front are placed in the **api_user** table and customers created in the backend are placed in the **customer_entity** table.

Anyone know why this is? Is it a latency from 1.3.2 and is hiccuping from our upgrade to 1.4.0.?

Thanks again for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

Well dibbly do. I solved this issue by going into:

Configuration > Customer Configuration > Share Customer Accounts > Global

Then, in the backend admin account creation I made sure to select the proper store for the customer being created.